# X and Y are normed linear spaces over the same field $F(=\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$, both having the same finite dimension $n$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

X and Y are normed linear spaces over the same field $F(=\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R})$, both having the same finite dimension $n$. I need to show that $X$ and $Y$ are topologically isomorphic ( A topological isomorphism is defined to be a mapping which is an isomorphism and homeomorphism)

Let $B_{X}$ and $B_Y$ be the basis elements for $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

Let $B_X=\{x_1,x_2,..,x_n\}, B_y=\{y_1,y_2,..,y_n\}$. Then it is natural to define $$\phi:X \to Y$$ such that $$\phi(x_i)=(y_i), i=1,2,..n$$ and $\phi(c)=c \forall c \in F$

Then clearly $\phi$ is an isomorphism. In a similar way $\phi^{-1}$ can be defined. All i need to show that $\phi$ is continuous.

Fix $\epsilon \gt 0$. Then whenever $$||a-b||_{X}=||\sum_{i=1}^n(c_i-d_i)x_i||_{X} \lt \delta$$

$$||\phi(a)-\phi(b)||_Y\le \sum_{i=1}^{n}|c_i-d_i|  {||\phi(x_i)||_Y}$$

Now since $x$ and $\phi(x)$ can be uniquely written as linear combinations of $c_i$ and $d_i$, (both in $F$), I define a new norm On $X$ and $Y$ by setting $||x||_{0,X}=max_{i}|c_i|$ and $||\phi(x)||_{0,Y}=max_{i}|d_i|$. It is easy to see that both these are norms. Now since in any finite dimensional space, all norms are equivalent, there are constants $k_1 \gt 0$ and $k_2 \gt 0$   such that $$||.||_{o,Y} \le k_1 ||.||_{0} \le k_2 ||.||_{o,X}$$
And we are done.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: You have to show your mapping is bounded. That's all.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Can you have a look now??

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a finite-dimensional complex normed space with basis $\{ x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_N \}$, then you can define $L : \mathbb{C}^{N} \rightarrow X$ by $$
   L(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)=\alpha_1 x_1+\alpha_2 x_2+\cdots +\alpha_N x_N.
$$
This map is continuous because
$$
\begin{align}
   \|L(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)\|_{X}
       & \le |\alpha_1|\|x_1\|+\cdots+|\alpha_N|\|x_N\| \\
       & \le \left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}|\alpha_n|^{2}\right)^{1/2}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{N}\|x_n\|^{2}\right)^{1/2} \\
       & \le C\|(\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n)\|_{\mathbb{C}^{N}},
\end{align}
$$
where $C$ is a positive real constant. The unit sphere $S = \{ x \in \mathbb{C}^{N} : \|x\|_{\mathbb{C}^{N}}=1 \}$ is compact, and the map
$F(x) = \|Lx\|_{X}$ is continuous on $\mathbb{C}^{N}$ and non-vanishing on $S$; hence, attains $F$ its minimum value $\rho > 0$. So $F(x) \ge \rho > 0$ for all $\|x\|_{\mathbb{C}^{N}}=1$. That gives,
$$
              \rho \le \left\|L\frac{1}{\|x\|_{\mathbb{C}^{N}}}x\right\|_{X}, \\
          \rho \|x\|_{\mathbb{C}^{N}} \le \|Lx\|_{X} \le C\|x\|_{\mathbb{C}^{N}}.
$$
Therefore $L : \mathbb{C}^{N} \rightarrow X$ is continuous, and its inverse is continuous. Your map $\phi$ is built from $L_1 L_2^{-1}$, where $L_j$ are maps such as $L$.

Comment: Can you look at the question now and see if my attempt is correct?

Comment: @tattwamasiamrutam : I've proved the equivalence of norms in what I gave you because I was not sure what you knew. If you want to invoke equivalence of norms on finite dimension spaces, then all you have to do is to note that $\phi : X \rightarrow Y$ induces a norm on $X$ using the norm of $Y$: $\|x\|_{X}'=\|\phi(x)\|_{Y}$. So this norm is equivalent to the norm on $X$. That is $m_1 \|\phi(x)\|_{Y} \le \|x\|_{X} \le M_1 \|\phi(x)\|_{Y}$. The first inequality gives you continuity of $\phi$, while the second gives continuity of its inverse.